# Javascript - get number of elements in Document Fragment

Tags: javascript, object, documentfragment

I'm creating a counter by passing a number to following function:

```
function numberToHtml(n) {
            function createSpan(n) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.textContent = n;
                return span;
            }
            function iter(n, container) {
                if (n === '') return container;
                container.insertBefore(createSpan(n.slice(-3)), container.firstChild);
                return iter(n.slice(0,-3), container);
            }
            return iter(String(n), document.createDocumentFragment());
        }
```

This returns:

```
DocumentFragment [ <span>, <span> ]
```

I'm havibng trouble to get a number of elements in the DocumentFragment. I tried `$(myobject).length`, which returns 1.

How can I get the no of items in my DocumentFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my first answer wasn't correct. I had trouble figuring out, how you got your outcome (that would have been helpfull). What you are looking for is:

```
var myobject = numberToHtml(3231123123);
var length = $(myobject).children().length;
alert(length); // 4
```

or as juhana pointed out, you can omit the jquery wrapper:

```
var myobject = numberToHtml(3231123123);
var length = myobject.children.length;
alert(length); // 4
```

Since the span elements are added as children, you want to count the children of the container.

Comment: The jQuery wrapper is unnecessary. `myobject.children.length` works too.

Comment: okay. didn't noticed that. looks like I have to less with Jquery, to get back to basics. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var me = numberToHtml(123455);
alert( me.childElementCount);
```

alerts 2
 NOTE: also `me.children.length` returns 2

To see what you have to work with do this:

`console.dir(me);`

then expand that in the console.